# DownloadManager vs InputStream.read()

Tags: android, download, android-download-manager, android-ion

I have 2 simple implementation of `DownloadManager` and custom download task:

- `DownloadManager`

  ```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...
   mDownloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
  }

  private void startDownload(String link) 
   Uri uri=Uri.parse(link);

   DownloadManager.Request req = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

   req.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
          | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
          .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
          .setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false)
          .setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
          .setDescription(getString(R.string.waiting_for_downloading))
          .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(dataPath,fileName);

   lastDownload = mDownloadManager.enqueue(req);
  }

  private void queryStatus() {
   Cursor c = mDownloadManager.query(new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(lastDownload));

   if (c == null) return;

   switch (c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS))) {
          case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED:
              downloadError();
              break;
          case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING:
              ...
              break;
          case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
              ...
              break;
          default: break;
      }
      c.close();
   }
  ```
- custom download task

  ```
  new AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>() {
   @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
      try {
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(saveFile);
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();

      } catch (Exception e) {
           downloadError();
          }
     return null;
    }
  }
  ```

in general cases both methods works ok, but on some devices *(for ex xiaomi android 6)* `DownloadManager` works 2-3 times slower or i got `DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED` error. but why? is `DownloadManager` unstable? or it's smth about settings?

p.s: i would like to use `DownloadManager` because of customization that i shouldn't implement by myself like set up allowed network or show progress in notification area.

**update v0.1**

1) I have handler that called `queryStatus()` check one time per 1 sec.

2) trying to connect to another `wi-fi` network with nexus phone - `DownloadManager` works ok, but custom implementation fails...

**update v0.2**

tried to call `AsyncTask` downloader from `Service` *(to continue download in case user close the app without canceling process)*, UI updates via `BroadcastReceiver` + `sendBreadcase()` call from the `Service` - result: downloading became several times slower and now (from time to time) I got an `unexpected end of stream` exception. [Trying the same files I've downloaded when makes call from `Activity`]

**update v0.3**

forgot to notice: `DownloadManager` fails with `1008` reason = `ERROR_CANNOT_RESUME`

tried [ION](https://github.com/koush/ion) also. looks if works better than `DownloadManager` but some times got an error `End of data reached before content length was read: 70385664/77217546`

so, still looking the most stable solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok... there was a lot of tests passed with different wi-fi connections and set of devices. `ION` grant the most stable results.